# no implicit conversion of Float into Stringが解消できない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

現在Ruby on Railsにてコントローラーのテストを行っております。
以下のエラーが解消できません。

bundle exec rspec spec/requests/nutritions_spec.rbの実行結果

```
     Failure/Error: expect(response.body).to include @nutrition.calorie

 TypeError:
   no implicit conversion of Float into String
 # ./spec/requests/nutritions_spec.rb:21:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

nutritionsコントローラーというもののテストコードを記述しております。その際に以下のようなテストコードを書いております。そのうち、「indexアクションにリクエストするとレスポンスに登録済みの食品名が存在する」「indexアクションにリクエストするとレスポンスに登録済みのカロリーが存在する」にて同一のエラー分が返ってきます。

【nutritions_spec.rb】

```
    describe NutritionsController, type: :request do

  before do
    @nutrition = FactoryBot.create(:nutrition)
  end



  describe "GET #index" do
    it "indexアクションにリクエストすると正常にレスポンスが返ってくる" do
      get root_path
      expect(response.status).to eq 200
    end
    it "indexアクションにリクエストするとレスポンスに登録済みの食品名が存在する" do
      get root_path
      expect(response.body).to include @nutrition.ingredient
    end
    it "indexアクションにリクエストするとレスポンスに登録済みのカロリーが存在する" do
      get root_path
      expect(response.body).to include @nutrition.calorie
    end
    it "indexアクションにリクエストするとレスポンスに登録済みのタンパク質が存在する" do
      get root_path
      expect(response.body).to include @nutrition.protein
    end

    it "indexアクションにリクエストするとレスポンスに投稿検索フォームが存在する" do
    end
  end
end
```

float型であることに文句を言われているのでFactoriesが怪しいなと思い、色々型を変えてみたのですが、解決できませんでした。
【factories/nutritions.rb】

```
  factory :nutrition do

    ingredient {Faker::Lorem.sentence}
    calorie {"300"}
    protein {"300"}
    lipid {"300"}
    carbohydrate {"300"}
    potassium {"300"}
    calcium {"300"}
    iron {"300"}
    vitamin_a {"300"}
    vitamin_b1 {"300"}
    vitamin_b2 {"300"}
    vitamin_c {"300"}
    dietary_fiber {"300"}
    association :user
  end
end
```

対象のindex.html.erbは以下です。

```
<div class="index-contents">
  <div class="index-image">
    <%= image_tag ('/index3.jpg') %>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="index-text">
  Beriiesは食材の各栄養素を管理できるアプリです。<br>
  食材一覧からお好みの食材の栄養素をチェックしてみましょう。
</div>


<%= form_with(url: search_nutritions_path, local: true, method: :get, class: "search-form") do |form| %>
  <%= form.text_field :keyword, placeholder: "さっそく食材を検索しよう！", class: "search-input" %>
  <%= form.submit "Search", class: "search-btn" %>
  <% if user_signed_in? %>
  <div>検索しても無ければここから食材を登録しよう！</div>
  <div class="index-new">
    <%= link_to "食品登録", new_nutrition_path, class: "new-btn" %>
  </div>
  <% else %>
  <div class="index-new">
    <p class="letter-spacing"> 登録がなかったら新規登録してみましょう！<br>初めての方はここからかんたんログイン！</p>
    <%= link_to 'かんたんログイン', users_guest_sign_in_path, method: :post, class: "new-btn"%>
    <p class="login-select"> 登録済みの方　　新規会員登録</p>
    <%= link_to "Log In", new_user_session_path, class: "new-btn2" %>
    <%= link_to "Sign Up", new_user_registration_path, class: "new-btn2" %>
  </div>
  <% end %>


<% end %>

<script src="delete.js"></script>

<div class='main-contents'>

    <h1 class="contents-title">食品一覧<EM STYLE="font-size: large;">(100gあたり)</EM></h1>
    <table border="5" width="80%" cellpadding="20" bordercolor="#882d91" class="contents-column" align="left">
      <tr class="column-name">
        <th width="30%" height="50">食品名</th>
        <th class="column-color1" width="15%">エネルギー(kcal)</th>
        <th class="column-color1" width="15%">タンパク質(g)</th>
        <th class="column-color1" width="15%">脂質(g)</th>
        <th class="column-color1" width="15%">炭水化物(g)</th>
        <th class="column-color2" width="15%">カリウム(mg)</th>
        <th class="column-color2" width="15%">カルシウム(mg)</th>
        <th class="column-color2" width="15%">鉄(mg)</th>
        <th class="column-color3" width="15%">ビタミンA(mg)</th>
        <th class="column-color3" width="15%">ビタミンB1(mg)</th>
        <th class="column-color3" width="15%">ビタミンB2(mg)</th>
        <th class="column-color3" width="15%">ビタミンC(mg)</th>
        <th width="15%">食物繊維(g)</th>
        <%#<th width="15%">登録ユーザー</th>%>
      </tr>

      <% @nutritions.each do |nutrition| %>
        <tr height="60" class="content-post">
          <%# サインインしているかつ、お気に入り登録している食品は★がつき、カラーは赤になる%>
          <% if user_signed_in? %>
            <% if current_user.already_favorited?(nutrition, current_user) %>
              <td class="ingredient-column fav-color" id="ingredient-column">★<%= nutrition.ingredient %>
            <% else %>
              <td class="ingredient-column" id="ingredient-column"><%= nutrition.ingredient %>
            <% end %>
          <% else %>
            <td class="ingredient-column" id="ingredient-column"><%= nutrition.ingredient %>
          <% end %>
          <div class="more" id="more">
            <ul class="more-list" id="more-list">
              <li>
                <% if user_signed_in? %>
                  <% if current_user.already_favorited?(nutrition, current_user) %>
                    <%# 解除の引数としてid:0を渡しているがこれが無いとidがないというエラーが起きてしまうので応急処置 %>
                    <%= link_to '解除', nutrition_favorites_path(user_id:current_user.id, nutrition_id:nutrition.id, id:0), :style=>"color:green;", method: :delete %>
                  <% else %>
                    <%= link_to '登録', user_favorites_path(user_id:current_user.id, nutrition_id:nutrition.id), :style=>"color:green;", method: :post %>
                  <% end %>
                  <% if current_user.id == nutrition.user.id %>
                    <%= link_to '編集', edit_nutrition_path(nutrition.id), :style=>"color:green;", method: :get %>
                    <%= link_to '削除', nutrition_path(nutrition.id), :style=>"color:green;", method: :delete, data: { confirm: '削除しますか？'} %>
                  <% end %>
                <% end %>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        <td><%= number_with_precision(nutrition.calorie, precision: 1, strip_insignificant_zeros: true) %></td>
        <td><%= number_with_precision(nutrition.protein, precision: 1, strip_insignificant_zeros: true) %></td>
        <td><%= number_with_precision(nutrition.lipid, precision: 1, strip_insignificant_zeros: true) %></td>
        <td><%= number_with_precision(nutrition.carbohydrate, precision: 1, strip_insignificant_zeros: true) %></td>
        <td><%= number_with_precision(nutrition.potassium, precision: 1, strip_insignificant_zeros: true) %></td>
        <td><%= number_with_precision(nutrition.calcium, precision: 1, strip_insignificant_zeros: true) %></td>
        <td><%= number_with_precision(nutrition.iron, precision: 1, strip_insignificant_zeros: true) %></td>
        <td><%= number_with_precision(nutrition.vitamin_a, precision: 1, strip_insignificant_zeros: true) %></td>
        <td><%= number_with_precision(nutrition.vitamin_b1, precision: 1, strip_insignificant_zeros: true) %></td>
        <td><%= number_with_precision(nutrition.vitamin_b2, precision: 1, strip_insignificant_zeros: true) %></td>
        <td><%= number_with_precision(nutrition.vitamin_c, precision: 1, strip_insignificant_zeros: true) %></td>
        <td><%= number_with_precision(nutrition.dietary_fiber, precision: 1, strip_insignificant_zeros: true) %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </table>
</div>
```

また、マイグレーションファイルは以下になります。

```
  def up
    change_column :nutritions, :protein, :float
    change_column :nutritions, :lipid, :float
    change_column :nutritions, :carbohydrate, :float
    change_column :nutritions, :potassium, :float
    change_column :nutritions, :calcium, :float
    change_column :nutritions, :iron, :float
    change_column :nutritions, :vitamin_a, :float
    change_column :nutritions, :vitamin_b1, :float
    change_column :nutritions, :vitamin_b2, :float
    change_column :nutritions, :vitamin_c, :float
    change_column :nutritions, :dietary_fiber, :float
    rename_column :nutritions, :dietary_fiber, :dietary_fiber
  end
end
```

お力添頂けますと幸いです。

Comment: 質問の『そのうち』というのは、どのような操作なりコード変更なりをした後なのでしょうか？

Comment: [対象のindex.html.erbは以下です]に書かれているコードの４行目の</div>に対応する<div>がありません。先頭の部分が抜けているのではないでしょうか？ご確認ください。

Comment: ご返信ありがとうございます。2つ目の<div>の件につきましては、私のここに記載する際の記入ミスでした。修正させていただきました。

Comment: 「そのうち」は以下のコードが対象です。
 it "indexアクションにリクエストするとレスポンスに登録済みのカロリーが存在する" do
      get root_path
      expect(response.body).to include @ nutrition.calorie
    end
    it "indexアクションにリクエストするとレスポンスに登録済みのタンパク質が存在する" do
      get root_path
      expect(response.body).to include @ nutrition.protein
    end

ご確認のほどよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: "response.body"は文字列だと思いますが、どのような文字列なのですか？
”@nutrition.calorie”がその文字列に含まれるかどうかを調べようとしたが、@nutrition.calorieがfloat型なので、それを文字列に変換して、”response.body”に含まれるかを確かめようとした。しかし、floatを文字列に変換するところでエラーとなった。　こういうシナリオではないかと想像します。
@netrition.calorieをint型にすると、エラーが出なくなるのではないでしょうか？